# Assets files and folder not showing in backend octobercms

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I am new to OctoberCMS,

here I face the one issue, that's assets files and folder not showing in backend. I didn't know this was default feature or I made a mistake here while installing files.

For quick understand, I attached the images.

**cms/assests in backend**

[image]

`assets` folder file structure:

[image]

Please suggest to retrieve the assets in backend or please let me know the reason why its not showing in backend?

Thanks